# Mongoose and connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, mongoose, session-cookies

I am using mongoose for managing relationships between data and I am trying to use connect-mongo to store specific sessions in the database.

It looks like that we need to connect twice to the db, one with mongoose and another one with connect-mongo.

I am using the following code to initialise a connection for mongoose

```
await mongoose.connect(this._connectionUrl, this._connectionOptions);
```

Initialising a new store every time (not sure if I am correct regarding code initialisation).

```
app.use(session({
            // secret: config.sessionSecretKey,
            secret: "secretkey",
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: { maxAge: 19 * 60000 }, // store for 19 minutes
            store: MongoStore.create({
                mongoUrl: this._connectionUrl,
                mongoOptions: this._connectionOptions // See below for details
            })
        }))
```

Is there any way that I can pass the connection from mongoose to mongo-connect Store?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i'm lookin for a solution too and just read this on the "migration guide" of connect-mongo

> For the options, you should make the following changes:
>
> Change url to mongoUrl Change collection to collectionName if you are
> using it Keep clientPromise if you are using it mongooseConnection has
> been removed. Please update your application code to use either
> mongoUrl, client or clientPromise To reuse an existing mongoose
> connection retreive the mongoDb driver from you mongoose connection
> using Connection.prototype.getClient() and pass it to the store in the
> client-option. Remove fallbackMemory option and if you are using it,

and there's this example https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/master/example/mongoose.js

Answer (score 4):

I've just been digging through the docs and through a few other SO responses. I've found this works really well with the new version of `connect-mongo`.

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

app.use(
    session({
        secret: "secretkey",
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { maxAge: 19 * 60000 }, // store for 19 minutes
        store: MongoStore.create({
            client: mongoose.connection.getClient()
        })
    })
);
```

It is recommended by the devs for `connect-mongo` to utilise the connection object for `mongoose` to retrieve the client to ride the same connection so you don't have to setup two separate connections. This seems like a really clean way to do it but comment if you spot anything off!

This was pulled from the bottom of the `connect-mongo` migration guide [here](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/HEAD/MIGRATION_V4.md)

Comment: This must be the right answer